# what is the data format of axios error info?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, axios

when i use console.log(error),it will output

```
Error: Request failed with status code 400
at myError (myError.js:15)
at settle (settle.js:18)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:77)
```

when i use console.log(JSON.stringify(error)),it will output

```
"response": {
"data": {
  "errorList": [
    {
      "errorCode": "E0100002",
      "errorMessage": "没有权限"
    }
  ]
},
"status": 400,
"statusText": "",
"headers": {
  "cache-control": "max-age=0",
  "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
},
"config": {
  "transformRequest": {},
  "transformResponse": {},
  "timeout": 0,
  "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
  "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
  "maxContentLength": -1,
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "Accept-Language": "zh-CN"
  },
  "method": "get",
  "params": {
    "_t": 222,
    "_bqq_csrf": "555"
  },
  "url": "abc.com/*/*/*",
  "withCredentials": true,
  "promise": {}
},
"request": {
  "emonitorAjaxURL": "abc/*/*"
}
}
```

why the console.log(error) can output the error stack info the console.log(JSON.stringify(error)) does not have.What is actually the data format of the axios error?How much info does the error store that I have not output totally?

Comment: does anybody know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axios [augments request-related errors](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/371d8eac7927efb66a0a0e48cb7495fab0ff17d2/lib/core/enhanceError.js#L13) ([network errors](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/371d8eac7927efb66a0a0e48cb7495fab0ff17d2/lib/adapters/xhr.js#L83), [timeout errors](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/371d8eac7927efb66a0a0e48cb7495fab0ff17d2/lib/adapters/xhr.js#L95), and [aborts](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/371d8eac7927efb66a0a0e48cb7495fab0ff17d2/lib/adapters/xhr.js#L73)) with several properties, including [`toJSON()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description), which customizes how `JSON.stringify()` formats the resulting string. The string should show several more properties than the one you've shown (I assume you've only copied an excerpt).

The stack trace shown in the console comes from the corresponding `Error` object.